# Convert "var touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()" to Swift 1.2

Tags: swift

Just recently Apple released an update to Swift and Xcode.

I am using Swift

I had this line of code before the update:

```
var touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
```

What is the exact equivalent of this line of code in Swift 1.2?

----UPDATE - FOUND SOLUTION----

What was really confusing me, is that al of the places I was looking at had an if statement to find the location.

Like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
    // ...
}
super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
```

}

I found out that I could do this:

```
var location =  CGPoint()
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
```

In which location is now the location of the touch as a CGPoint.

Comment: To migrate your code to Swift 1.2 , click the Edit menu, then choose Convert > To Swift 1.2.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it said that there was nothing to be fixed; which was odd

Answer (score 0):

It is touches an optional? If it is try this

```
var touch = touches?.anyObject()
```